# How to send ZRank in IOREDIS

Tags: node.js, command, ioredis

I am new to Nodejs and I am using **ioredis** to send redis commands to my cluster.

I couldn't find any ioredis sample of how to use the **zrank command in ioredis**, except the basic 'get' and 'set' commands.

I know ioredis implemments it, but the parameters and callbacks is a mistery for me.

Thanks and sorry if the question might be duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this. The key and the member name. If the member is not found in the key, `null` is returned (and other rules as in the docs [here](http://redis.io/commands/zrank))

```
//redis.client established elsewhere (server startup)

redis.client.zrank( keyOfSortedSet, memberOfSortedSet )
.then(function(rank){
  console.log('the rank of ' + memberOfSortedSet + ' was ' + rank );
})
```

Comment: Thanks Clay! That Worked fine. I also could do it using this: 

redis.client.zrank(key, member, callback);

Comment: Great, glad it worked! `ioredis` supports promises or callbacks, good stuff : )